# Create programmable snippet for Visual Studio with Node.js code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, code-snippets

I would like to create curried functions in TypeScript, but the typing can be a bit tedious. I thought it would be easy to write a snippet for it but don't even know where to begin, I looked up programmable snippets but didn't really come up with anything.

So, here is what I would like to do:

Highlight a line similar to this (with a variable number of parameters):

```
var myFunc = (item: string, num: number): string => {
```

or

```
function myFunc (item: string, num: number): string {
```

or

```
var myFunc = <MyFunc> _.curry((item: string, num: number): string => {
```

and produce something like this:

```
interface MyFunc {
  (item: string, num: number): string
  (item: string): (num: number) => string
}

var myFunc = <MyFunc> _.curry((item: string, num: number): string => {
```

Comment: As far as I know there isn't an option. FYI we are thinking about something like this for `atom-typescript` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/5

Comment: Related wishlist: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/312